# Show more in Autocomplete reference content than the title (id)

Tags: views, 8, entities, nodes, ajax

In the Edit Content Page I try to see in the autocomplete field of type reference not only the title (node reference + ID) but also *another field* of my chose. Can I do that in Drupal 8 trough a view?

I tried already this with a view and now i can search the right reference but i cant see the *other field*. I write in the autocomplete field the content of the *other field* and I can see the right title (ID), but I can't visualize the *other field* itself.

I want to do this because I have many content with the same name and when I have to choose a reference to the right one I need to distinguish them trough another field directly in the autocomplete.

I already tried what this other answer suggested but without luck: [Show node IDs along with titles in Entity reference Autocomplete list](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187869/show-node-ids-along-with-titles-in-entityreference-autocomplete-list)
And also this one: [Node edit form with entity reference - show more than just the title in the autocomplete box](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128302/node-edit-form-with-entity-reference-show-more-than-just-the-title-in-the-auto)

Can be a bug in Drupal 8, or am I missing something?

Comment: I think autocompletes only operate on the first field in the View - you should be able to rewrite the results for the title field to combine it with the other field via tokens

Comment: I tried also without autocomplete. I tried with "check boxes/radio buttons" and "select list" trough a view but only the title is displayed.

Comment: Autocomplete itself works (trough a view can operate also on another field). But it doesn't show the content of the other field. (it can only search but not visualize)

Comment: See http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215023/changing-the-text-displayed-in-an-entity-reference-autocomplete/215052#215052