# Entity reference views display options

Tags: views, 8, entities

Setting up a view and displaying it as a reference method for an entity reference field is pretty straight forward in D8. ([a very good tutorial in case anyone needs](http://www.jackrabbithanna.com/articles/creating-entity-reference-view))

In a few easy steps you can configure the few to your liking with **search fields** and **inline fields**. In my case it is a content view and **the sample output I get in the views configuration page is:**

```
Title / Field1 / Field2
```

which is perfectly how it should look like.

The problem is, in content form, I only get the **Title** listed. The search fields work very well but only the title is displayed in the entity reference field option list. I tried **Select list** (Chosen enabled or not), **Autocomplete**, **Checkboxes/radio buttons**. Also tried to rewrite results on various fields.

What am I missing here?

[image: view]

[image: Create unit]

Comment: Can you post screenshot here for better understanding?

Comment: @AjayReddy hi, I uploaded images.

Comment: So you are saying Title and Unit Count not combining in the Select list right. In that case click Unit count and under rewrite results select "Override the output of this field with custom text" and combine both Title and Unit count using replacement patterns. And also don't forgot to "Exclude from display" of Title field. Hope this will help.

Comment: @AjayReddy already tried. No go. I think this might be duplicate: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215023/changing-the-text-displayed-in-an-entity-reference-autocomplete/215052#215052